# How to resolve internal error - server connection terminated while posting content to URL

Tags: libcurl

I am trying to POST content to URL using CURL.
My code snippet is as follows

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, "proxy.xyz.com:8080");
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "uname:password");
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, jsonResult.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "url");
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
  /* provide a buffer to store errors in */
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, error);

res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
if(res != CURLE_OK)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
    curl_easy_strerror(res));
    printf("unable to send data");
    return false;
}
```

When I run above code snippet,it is always giving **internal error - server connection terminated**
Can anyon eplease let me know what could be the cause and how to resolve

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That error message you see is actually in the HTTP response body - probably a response from the proxy given the meaning of it.